# Can't access TPU from VM in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-tpu, tpu

Trying to run this code

```
import os import tensorflow as tf from tensorflow.contrib 


import tpu from tensorflow.contrib.cluster_resolver import TPUClusterResolver

def axy_computation(a, x, y):   return a * x + y

inputs = [
    3.0,
    tf.ones([3, 3], tf.float32),
    tf.ones([3, 3], tf.float32), ]

tpu_computation = tpu.rewrite(axy_computation, inputs)

tpu_grpc_url = TPUClusterResolver(
    tpu=["sahil-wadhwa"], zone="us-central1-b").get_master()

with tf.Session(tpu_grpc_url) as sess:   
sess.run(tpu.initialize_system())   
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())   
output = sess.run(tpu_computation)   
print(output)   
sess.run(tpu.shutdown_system())
```

However I get the following error,

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://tpu.googleapis.com/v1alpha1/projects/nlp-research-198620/locations/us-central1-b/nodes/sahil-wadhwa?alt=json
>   returned "Permission 'tpu.nodes.get' denied on
>   'projects/nlp-research-198620/locations/us-central1-b/nodes/sahil-wadhwa'">

Can somebody tell what permissions I need to provide my VM or TPU to run this smoothly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ctpu](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/quickstart) tool automates a lot of these steps and is the recommended way to create the TPU and VM.

If you prefer to create the VM manually you need to add the cloud-platform authentication scope to your VM as described here

```
gcloud compute instances create tpu-demo-vm \
  --machine-type=n1-standard-2 \
  --image-project=ml-images \
  --image-family=tf-1-11 \
  --scopes=cloud-platform
```

https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/custom-setup#create_resources

Answer (score 1):

Michaelb's answer works, though it's also possible to change the permissions on an existing VM in the console. You have to stop the VM, then edit it to allow read/write access to the compute engine api. To do this, click on the name of the VM then click edit in the top bar; the api access settings are towards the bottom of the page.